# Cant find the Extensions namespace in MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

The sample for building a context for EF Core at [Oracle](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core-example.html) has the following code that seems to be out of date:

```
using MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions;
```

It doesn't seem that there is an Extensions namespace in this package. Is there a pointer to a more up to date example?

Thank you.

Kevin

Comment: I have never used this before, however out of sheer boredom and morbid curiosity, I downloaded the nuget with its 1 billion dependencies and tried to use a class in the extension namespace `MySQLServiceCollectionExtensions` and it worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahh I see what's happening

you have

```
using MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions;
```

Where the *namespace* is actually

```
using MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions;
```

`MySql` is not uppercase

However rather confusingly they are both valid *namespaces*

```
using MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

With the exception that the `Extensions` is not in `MySQL`

It looks like someone messed-up the naming, highlighted in the below image by my *badly-hewn* red *circleish* scribble, it maybe a bug, but who knows

[image]